# Where to get help for accidental spend?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-billing

A script recently got away from me and spent nearly $1k the other night, which I just saw when poking around my Google Billing dashboard. I have an account without a support plan, so I'm unsure of how to contact Google regarding this concern if there is even anything they can do. I know it was my fault, but I'm hoping there are some additional credits I can apply for, or that they can give me a partial break on my bill since I immediately ended the API usage that drove up the cost.

What's more, the link provided in the console for billing questions is broken: https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/api_billing_support

It would seem there is no way to contact a human without buying a support package, which feels a bit odd since it is a billing question. Has anyone else found a way through?

Comment: If it was GCP APIs you were using ... this might be useful ...
https://cloud.google.com/support/billing

Comment: For Billing you have Chat support available: 
https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a support question for Google, not a programming question.

Comment: @BSMP I support that motion, it's somewhat infuriating that Google links you stack-overflow as the place to ask questions like this if you aren't paying for their support.

Comment: There's a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/users-doing-google-first-level-customer-support) about this (though there isn't a whole lot of discussion yet). If it's a problem, usually a Stack Overflow employee reaches out and they get it resolved.